# Is there a straightforward way to combine these two steps into one formula?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have some data in cells A1:D5.

In cells F1:F5, I calculate some kind of geometric average for each row (column A through D). This is the intermediate step.

Finally, in cell F7, I take the median of the values of the previous step.

[image]

Is there a way to skip the intermediate step and have cell F7 do all the work by itself, without copying the five formulas above into it? (I want it to remain flexible, so it would also work for larger data sets.)

Comment: Possible on `Microsoft-365`. Are you on Excel-2010?

Comment: @Harun24hr No, I clicked the wrong tag. Fixed. Pls show me on 365 if you know how.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On `Microsoft-365` you may utilize `BYROW()` function. Give a try on-

```
=MEDIAN(BYROW(A1:D5,LAMBDA(x,EXP(AVERAGE(LN(1+x)))-1)))
```

Comment: If it solve your current issue then please accept the answer (tick mark) to treat the thread as solved.